# Why is undefine for the destructing variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Whay the values of destructing variables are undefine?
I also referenced in "..developer.mozilla.org", but, what is wrong?
here is my javascript code snippet =>

```
let myid, myname, myage;
// let person = [1, 'Kyaw Kyaw', 25];
// [myid, myname, myage] = person;
({ myid, myname, myage } = { id: 1, name: "Kyaw Kyaw", age: 25 });
console.log(myid);
console.log(myname);
console.log(myage);
```

When I got output for these variables, they are all 'undefine'!
What is wrong? Very interesting!!

Comment: You still need to tell the destructuring assignment which of the right hand properties map to which one of the left hand properties (as the names are not identical).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destructuring objects is based on the **name** of the variable and the property, not the **order**.

`myid` is a different name to `id` so it doesn't match.

`yourobject.myid` is `undefined`.

If you want to store the value in a variable name that **doesn't** match the property name, then you have to specify that explicitly with the format: `property_name: variable_name`

```js
const my_object = { id: 1, name: "Kyaw Kyaw", age: 25 };

console.log(my_object.myid);

let { id: myid, name: myname, age: myage } = my_object;
console.log(myid);
console.log(myname);
console.log(myage);
```

Comment: Woow, I got it!! Thanks so much @Quentin!

Comment: In this case, I must set the destructor var-names as equla as assigned object.

Comment: must same property name! Right! I already noted!! Thanks for all